# MVC3 pass the parameter using beginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parameters

I want to pass the parameter which is rentalPeriod using Html.BeginForm.
Currently, I put just text in Details.cshtml. 
If I want to pass the rentalPeriod such as 3, 7, 14 as a number, what do I have to do?
Do I have to use hiddenfield or a function?
I don't know how to pass the parameter to my other method which is AddToCart method.
Please let me know how to pass the value of the number.
Thanks.

Details.cshtml.

```
<td>
        Rental Period: <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.productId }, FormMethod.Post))
        { 
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, Model.threeDayPrice) 
            //I put just text in here '3 day' How can I write this number, '3'?
            //do I have to use hiddenfield? or other functions?
            3 day: £@Model.threeDayPrice
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, Model.aWeekPrice)
            1 week: £@Model.aWeekPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.twoWeekPrice)
            2 week: £@Model.twoWeekPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.aMonthPrice)
            1 month: £@Model.aMonthPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.threeMonthPrice)
            3 month: £@Model.threeMonthPrice 
            </div>
            <div class="display-label">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.price, @Model.sixMonthPrice)
            6 month: £@Model.sixMonthPrice 
            </div>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add to cart" style="margin-left:0px; width:90px;"/>
        }      
    </td>
```

ShoppingCart controller in AddToCart method.

```
//How to pass the parameter here.
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddToCart(int id, FormCollection col)
    {
        var addedProduct = db.Product
            .Single(product => product.productId == id);
        decimal priceValue = Convert.ToDecimal(col["price"]);

        // Retrieve the product from the database
        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

        cart.AddToCart(addedProduct);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { @priceValue = priceValue });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you use [View Models](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/mbrown/development/2139/mvc-3-view-models) rather than relying on the FormsCollection.  However, yes.. in your case you can just use a hidden field to store the item, then you pull it out of the FormsCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I got my value for a provider attribute to be associated with a checkbox, so that when the check box is checked, I can get it out of the forms collection in the Controller by querying formsCollection["selectedProviderLanID"].  You could do something similar with your radio buttons.

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.providerList)
{
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedProviderLanID" value="@item.LANID" />   
    </td>
    <td>
       @item.DisplayName
    </td>
    <td>
       @item.Pager
    </td>
</tr>
}
```